# Rails 3.2.10 Assets not precompiled in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

My css files are working fine in development.

My production app is failing with a 500 error. The production log file shows the css file being compiled

```
Compiled screen/fluid/nav.css  (0ms)  (pid 16607)
```

then this error:

```
Started GET "/login" for 118.211.236.235 at 2013-01-06 01:29:10 +0000
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 112ms

ActionView::Template::Error (avetmiss.css isn't precompiled):
```

The file is not listed in application.css but seems to be compiled anyway. Here is my application.css file:

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree ./screen
*/
```

A further issue is that I have print css in my application.html file like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application-print', :media => 'print' -%>
```

This file is not being precompiled at all. Do I need to place it in production.rb in a precompile directive like below? Should this directive go in production.rb or application.rb?

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( application-print.css )
```

Do I need to add every css and js file which isn't a controller asset in a precompile statement like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the files are not being included in the pre-compilation step of your deployment.

Assuming the application-print.css and avetmiss.css are in app/assets/stylesheets, require them in your application.css directly with

```
/*
*= require self
*= require tree ./screen
*= require avetmiss
*/
```

Alternatively, if you want to include all css files under your app/assets/stylesheets folder, then in your application.css, simply:

```
/*
*= require self
*= require tree .
*/
```

[The Rails Guide for Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) was very helpful for me.

***Edit

for your print css - I think you do need a precompile directive for it, so it will not be included in application.css

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( application-print.css )
```

Comment: This won't work for me as the application-print.css file contains a manifest to a print.css which will delete part of my layout. I need to have this file out of application.css.

Comment: I'f I'm not mistaken, adding the `config.assets.precompile += %w( application-print.css )` line to your production.rb file will keep it as a separate file.  I'm basing that on section 4.1 of the Rails Guide above.